# PHP/SQL - No Database Selected

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have tested my connection to the database and it comes up fine, until I attempt to Insert into the database... and I'm getting the error No Database Selected.   Tips/help would be greatly appreciated, as I am still very new to PHP!

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
    //connect to the database
    $con = new mysqli("localhost", "admin", "quixtar1");
    $con->select_db("attendance");
    //display success or failure
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error();
    }
    $ibonum = $_POST['num'];
    $course = $_POST['course'];

    $insert = "INSERT INTO tbltest (num, course) VALUES ($ibonum, $course)";

    $result = mysql_query($insert);
    if($result){
    echo("Success!");
    }
    else{
    echo ("Fail!  <br/>" . mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

Comment: You're mixing mysql and mysqli functions

Comment: mysqli != mysql. So if you use one, use it to the end

Comment: Plus, this `$course` - if that's not an `int`, quote it.

Comment: @JohnConde Cha-ching! Gin & tonic? Nah.

Comment: Ho btw, injecting $_POSTS directly to DB is the worse you can do... But that's not the original question, just a must warning

Comment: Thank you, it didn't even register that I was mixing the two together.

Comment: if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $var = stripslashes($var);
$var = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $var);

That's the basic trick, but there is more, please read about mysql injections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code should be

```
<?php
//connect to the database
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "admin", "quixtar1", "attendance");
//display success or failure
if ($con){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $con->connect_error;
    exit;
}
$ibonum = $con->real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['num']));
$course = $con->real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['course']));

$insert = "INSERT INTO tbltest (num, course) VALUES ('$ibonum', '$course')";

$result = $con->query($insert);
if($result){
  echo("Success!");
}
else{
echo ("Fail!  <br/>" . $con->error);
}
```

Comment: `mysql_error()` <= change that.

Comment: Remember, `mysqli_` and `mysql_` functions do not mix together on the same page/execution.

Comment: yap i know but i was seeing the major problem which was database selection ...